# How to get NavigationStack to retain NavigationPath state when switching views?

Tags: swiftui

I modified an app to use the new NavigationSplitView and NavigationStack, but I can't figure out how to have the NavigationPath retain the state when it's not the active view.

Below is some sample code. I run it on an iPad in landscape mode, or on a Mac (Designed for iPad). It starts with View1 selected and displays View1 in the details. I then tap on SubView and it pushes to SubView. If I then tap on View2, View2 is displayed in the details. If I tap on View1 again, View1 is back at it's root, and is no longer pushed to the SubView. How can I fix this so that when I go back to View1 it is still pushed to SubView?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewType: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
}

private var viewTypes = [
    ViewType(id: "View1"),
    ViewType(id: "View2"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var navigationModel = NavigationModel()
    @State var selection: Set<String> = [viewTypes[0].id]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(viewTypes, selection: $selection) { viewType in
                Text("\(viewType.id)")
            }
        } detail: {
            switch selection.first ?? "Unknown" {
            case "View1":
                View1()
            case "View2":
                View2()
            default:
                Text("Unknown")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(selection.first ?? "Unknown")
        .environmentObject(navigationModel)
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationModel: NavigationModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationModel.path) {
            Text("View1")
            NavigationLink("SubView", value: "SubView")
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                        .onAppear {
                            print((navigationModel.path.count))
                        }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            Text("View2")
        }
    }
}

final class NavigationModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath() {
        didSet {
            print("path.count: \(path.count)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding your `NavigationModel`

Comment: Sorry, I added the ```NavigationModel``` code to the end of the listing above.

Comment: did you ever find a solution @JeffZacharias?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution. It works fine with a tab view on an iPhone but I never got it to work on the iPad with NavigationSplitView.